# Extract out certain divs based on data attribute using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  ..More Divs
  <div>
    ...More Divs
    <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="false">
  </div> 
..More Divs


  <div >
    ...More Divs
    <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="false">
  </div> 
  <div>
    ...More Divs
    <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="false">
  </div> 

  <div data-action="Block">

    <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="false">
  </div> 
  <div data-action="Block">
    ...More Divs
    <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="false">
  </div>  
  <div data-action="Block">
    ...More Divs
    <input class="button-input" type="submit" value="false">
  </div> 
</div>
```

I am trying to get all the divs in parent which dont have data-action Block. I tried using the filter function to remove the Block data action attribute, but it didn't work. After filtering out the div which don't have action Block I need to perform an action on the input field which can be done with `.find('input[value="false"]')`

```
$.find(".parent").filter(function() { 
         return this.find("[data-action='Block']").length ==0;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try negating the attribute selector:

```
$("div:not([data-action=Block])",".parent")
```

the second attribute that you see `.parent` means that the function will try to find every div that doesn't have an attribute of `data-action=Block` inside that element

Comment: Updated Question. I have other divs as well which I missed out while framing the question. If I am performing the find of input tag on the parent level, it works, but I need to filter out the ones having the specific data attribute

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery's not function which will find all divs except those in the not selector.

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Updated Question. I have other divs as well which I missed out while framing the question. If I am performing the find of input tag on the parent level, it works, but I need to filter out the ones having the specific data attribute

Answer (score 0):

Chain the find method to narrow results:

```
$('.parent').find('> div:not([data-action="Block"])').find('input[value="false"]')
```

The result of the first find:

- First level divs inside parent, which don't have data-action="Block"

The second find will search inside the result of the first, the result will be:

- inputs with value false

Comment: This will select all the divs which don't have the data-action. I eventually want to select the input tag which doesn't have the data-action block tag

Comment: @user1692342 edited, this will give you the right elements: `$('.parent').find('div:not([data-action="Block"])').find('input[value="false"]')`

Comment: $('.parent').find('div:not([data-action="Block"])') will include divs within dataaction Block right except that specific line right?

Comment: try out, this will give you the first three inputs from the html snippet you attached, these value's are false and it's parent div doesn't have the data-attribute

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle. It selects all the divs

Comment: okey I see, I added `>` to select only the first level divs from parent

Comment: Is there any other way? Since my data-action Block is not a first level. It is very deeply nested one

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with the right HTML with deeply nested ones?
Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/xksfkm5m/

Comment: @user1692342 Please accept the answer if it helped you out